# Change value of selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, dropdown, html-select

I have dropdown select option countries:

```
    <select name="country" id="countryId" required="required"
class="countries order-alpha form-control custom-select bg-white border-left-0 border-md">
                                <option value="">Select Country</option>
                                <option value="1"> Afghanistan</option>
                                <option value="2"> Aland Islands</option>
                                <option value="3"> Albania</option>
                                <option value="4"> Algeria</option>
                                <option value="5"> American Samoa</option>
```

When I select country on change I get value(numeric) send it to server and get States list that parse in States same happen with cities.
After fill all fields, formData.serialized and send to server. Server get numeric id of country, state and city But I want send Name of country/state/ city. So before send I should change selected value to selected text(country name).
I try change like that:

```
$("#countryId").change(function () {
 c.countrytxt = $(this).find("option:selected").text(); // get text from option
 var countryId = $("#countryId").val(); // save for send as paramet to server
 document.getElementById('countryId').value = c.countrytxt; // try set county name to value
```

How could I achieve it?

Comment: why not simply send `c.countrytxt` to server when you want to submit the country name at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this instead.

```js
$("#countryId").change(function () {
  // get text from option
  countrytxt = $(this).find("option:selected").text(); 
  // save for send as paramet to server
  var countryId = $("#countryId").val(); 
  // try set county name to value
  $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value',countrytxt);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="country" id="countryId" required="required"
class="countries order-alpha form-control custom-select bg-white border-left-0 border-md">
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
  <option value="1"> Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="2"> Aland Islands</option>
  <option value="3"> Albania</option>
  <option value="4"> Algeria</option>
  <option value="5"> American Samoa</option>
</select>
```